# Why did my Window Layout changed in VS2010 from one day to an other?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for C++ in the default setting where the Solution Explorer and all the other tabs are on the left side. I got used to it.

Now today, I start Visual Studio and **Solution Explorer, Team Explorer, Class View moved to the right** side of the screen, while **Server Explorer and Toolbox appear on the left**, in a vertical auto-hiding tab. Also, the **Output window is now hidden**, as well as the other windows at the bottom of the screen.

I tried "**Reset Window Layout**" in the Window menu, but nothing changes. It seems that this is now the default layout.

**How can I get my old default layout back?**

When I clicked "Start debugging" for an aplication waiting for user input, while debugging, the good old, original layout appears. But when I finish debugging, the crazy new UI appears again.

**What made this new interface appear, and how can I get rid of it for good?**

*possible idea: I changed monitor from 1600x1200 to 1680x1050 a few days ago. But it worked OK in the first few days. Also, changing resoltion doesn't have any effect now.*

Also: If I want to start with a 100% clean VS2010, what are the user registry keys as well as user folders that I need to delete?

[image: new interface]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is what I had to do to reset everything to default settings:

**Tools \ Import and Export settings \ Reset all settings**

Comment: Thanks for sharing, usually "Reset Window Layout" worked for me but not this time.

Comment: I've got this for a long time, it not only appears in VS 2010, but also in vs 2008 and vs 2012(I mean RC for now).
Every time I meet this, I can only do Reset All Settings, but it's annoying to re-config my fonts, symbol server settings, etc, again and over again.
It seems the right side layout of solution explorer is for C#, while the left side is for C++. I mainly develop in C++ native, so when it's show on right side ,really annoying